# I've read that spontaneous symmetry breaking is similar to what happens in ferromagnetism, but are they similar mathematically?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, symmetry-breaking, ferromagnetism

Is it only an analogy? Similar to saying that the Higgs boson is like glass that slows down light and, thereby, seems to give it "mass"? I've looked up a little about ferromagnetism and potential energy isn't mentioned explicitly. I think I have a decent understanding of the Standard Model but I know nearly nothing about ferromagnetism (or the Ising model, paramagnetism, etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spontaneous symmetry breaking isn't defined to refer only to what the Higgs field does; it's a much more general phenomenon, of which ferromagnetism is an example. In fact, both examples result from the need to specify one vector of a given modulus. For Higgs, SSB amounts to [choosing a complex scalar's phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism#Abelian_Higgs_mechanism), or equivalently an arbitrary direction in $\Bbb R^2$. For ferromagnetism, [it happens in $\Bbb R^3$ instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization), but the principle is otherwise the same.